# What is very faster, normal for loop or foreach loop in java?

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

What is very faster, normal {for loop} or {foreach loop} in java ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They are different first of all. `for-each` uses `Iterator` under the hood whereas `for` is useful for operations on arrays or where you can do something meaningful with indexes.